# Angular with Nosql DB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, nosql

Is it advisable to build application with just Angular for the front-end and CouchDB/Cloudant or MongoDB as the database as these DB can serve JSON data directly? Will it work if I do NOT use any middleware in Java or Node or PHP?  I want to use Angular and any of the nosql DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use angular for front end and whatever server side language in the back end.  Regarding direct connection - you could query the DB directly. Each DB has a REST API that enables you to communicate with it directly from client. For instance, MongoDB has this: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/
Hope this helps.
If it is advisable? This is an opinion question and up for debate.

Comment: It is very likely not advisable. You do not want to be managing database credentials in your client-side code or need to rewrite the UI when the database you're using changes.

Comment: Its up for you to decide depending on your needs. You are correct that nowdays you would probably go for socket or some other api with a server between you and the db.  On the other hand the REST api is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks yccteam for your answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could technically develop a full-stack application only using AngularJS calling the REST API of a DBaaS, and it would work. However you should not do that, for the following reasons:

- All your business logic would run on the client side, and this means that anyone can see (and change!) in the browser all your business domain logic, your security controls, field validations and so on using tools such as FireBug or the developer tools contained in every browser
- Where would you put and manage your DB access credentials?
- You would get a code that is really difficult to manage, doesn't adapt easily to future changes

Remember the rule *high cohesion, loose coupling*.

Generally speaking you should always have some kind of server side logic layer (the "controller" if you are familiar with the  M-V-C framework) for all the above reasons and also to develop ***secure***,  ***reusable*** and ***maintainable*** code. If you need to implement a change in the business logic you go to the API code, if you need to change the entire persistence mechanism you have to edit the server-DB interaction, not the UI and so on... Otherwise every future change would impact the whole application. It's a good practice keeping separated modules with different responsibilities (how do we represent the data?, what needs to be carried out?, how do we render the result?).

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's tempting but discouraged. I did implement it in my own home automation web UI (angularjs actually) that was talking directly to RavenDB using REST and JSON.

Great for prototyping and acceptable for limited, controlled environment, but I eventually switched to a "middleman" API layer to handle some boring details like security (although in my case I then also introduced signalR real-time library so it was a UX benefit, not just technical one).